# How to add page refresh to bokeh output file?

Tags: html, refresh, bokeh

My goal is that my html file should be able to refresh itself in the browser.

```
title2 = Div(text='<head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="4></head>')
.
.
.
layout = column(title,grid,title2, sizing_mode='stretch_both')
```

I was able to put text into h1 element, so I was thinking that I can do with head element.

I manually copied the `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="4>` to html file head part and it did what I wanted.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are actually trying to accomplish (e.g. what is the actual problem that you think a page refresh is the solution for?) Regardless, you won't be able to add anything to `head` without JavaScript, so you are looking at using a `CusomJS` callback. But as long as you are doing that there are just JS APIs you could use directly AFAIK.

Comment: I run the python code with crontab in every 10 minutes. So, I want to refresh the browser to see the new datas.

Comment: You should probably just use more explicit [`file_html`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/output/embed.html#html-files) with your own page template, then you can just put the meta tag in the template directly.